# Can I use angular-selectize with require.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, selectize.js

angular-selectize.js needs selectize.js and angular.js to run. When I load those via require, no window.Selectize property gets exposed,which is needed by angular-selectize.js.

This is a snippet from selectize.js

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define('selectize', ['jquery','sifter','microplugin'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'), require('sifter'), require('microplugin'));
    } else {
        root.Selectize = factory(root.jQuery, root.Sifter, root.MicroPlugin);
    }
```

and a snippet from angular-selectize

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

  Selectize.defaults.maxItems = null; //default to tag editor

  var selectize,
      config = angular.extend({}, Selectize.defaults, selectizeConfig, scope.config);
    ........


}
```

which needs the Selectize property to be exposed, and since its not available, because selectize goes into the

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
```

, the global is not created and it errors out

So, whats the right way to use angular-selectize via require?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no right way to use angular-selectize via require. Also, let's be clear that there several different angular-selectize libraries out there. The one you're talking about -- and the most popular one -- is by github person `machineboy2045`. Even though the Selectize library itself is AMD-compatible, the people who worked on angular-selectize didn't concern themselves with AMD or CommonJS. And so Selectize.defaults.maxItems are already available to them at that point in time because they've loaded it globally via script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem and fixed by adding `Selectize` to `window`.

```
(function (define) {
    'use strict';
    var dependencies = [
        'selectize',
        'angular',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngSelectize',
        'ngLoad'
    ];
    define(dependencies, function (Selectize) {

      window.Selectize = Selectize; 
      ...
```